# Unable to cancel a dial pad in phone number

Tags: ios, swift, phone-call

I think so This question is not duplicate one. 
Call to phone number when touching cancel Action my app throws app to initial screen instead of displaying current screen.
Is this a bug in iOS11 or is there something that I am doing wrong from following code. this is my code.

```
@objc func CallAction(_ sender : UIButton)
    {
        var localDic :NSDictionary!
        if is_searching {
            localDic = searchingDataArray.object(at: sender.tag) as! NSDictionary
        }else
        {
            localDic = myStudentsArray.object(at: sender.tag) as! NSDictionary

        }

        let phoneNumber=localDic["contact_no"] as! String
        print("phoneNumber",phoneNumber )

        guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + phoneNumber) else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(number)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
guard let telNumber = URL(string: "telprompt://" + "+1234-567-89") else { return }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(telNumber)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

hope its works..

Comment: hi asim here my problem when ever i click on call option its showing two buttons, one is for call one is for cancel when i select cancel button instead of showing current screen its showing initial project screen.

Comment: should i need to add any extra code for me its not working.

Comment: debug the code and check from where its popToRootViewController